# How do I create a time interval for every 15 sec of the game time spawn pizza

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I create a time interval for pizza spawning? During the game time for every 15s start spawning pizza for 5 seconds and stop, then start spawning pizza again after 15s

```
   IEnumerator SpawnPizzaCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int spawnPointX = Random.Range(-18, -5);
            int spawnPointY = Random.Range(5, 0);
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPointX, spawnPointY, 0);
            Instantiate(Pizza, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        }
    }
void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnPizzaCoroutine());
    }
```

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based measurement function instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep track of the elapsed time between pizzas in a float type variable

```
private bool spawningPizza;
private float nextSpawnTime;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnPizzaCoroutine());
}

private IEnumerator SpawnPizzaCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        nextSpawnTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (nextSpawnTime >= 15)
        {
            spawningPizza = true;

            int spawnPointX = Random.Range(-18, -5);
            int spawnPointY = Random.Range(5, 0);
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPointX, spawnPointY, 0);
            Instantiate(Pizza, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

            nextSpawnTime = 0;
            spawningPizza = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: erm its not working it still spawns pizza every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `InvokeRepeating` for that purpose.
Have a look here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

You could execute the function every 20 seconds then your coroutine for 5 seconds. The result would be, that you spawn pizzas for 5 seconds and after 15 seconds another 5 seconds of pizza spawning would begin.

```
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnPizza", 15f, 20f);
    }   
    void SpawnPizza()
    {            
        StartCoroutine(SpawnPizzaCoroutine());
    }
  
    IEnumerator SpawnPizzaCoroutine(){
    startTime = Time.time;

    while (Time.time - startTime < 5f)
     {
       int spawnPointX = Random.Range(-18, -5);
       int spawnPointY = Random.Range(5, 0);
       Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPointX, spawnPointY, 0);
       Instantiate(Pizza, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
       yield return null;
      }
     }
```

Comment: It will spawn after 15s but it wont stop after 20s. My Game time is 1min

Comment: @Mike with this answer's example code, what did you write in the `SpawnPizzaCoroutine()`?

Comment: `code` add this   while (true)
        {
            
            int spawnPointX = Random.Range(-18, -5);
            int spawnPointY = Random.Range(5, 0);
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPointX, spawnPointY, 0);
            Instantiate(Pizza, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(PizzaWaitTime);
        }

Comment: @Mike the code you have provided will not work here. I have adjusted my answer with a possible implementation

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) for such a scenario. That calls a method for every x seconds.

```
public class PizzaMaker: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pizza;

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("makePizza", 15f, 15f);
    }

    void makePizza()
    {
        int spawnPointX = Random.Range(-18, -5);
        int spawnPointY = Random.Range(5, 0);
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPointX, spawnPointY, 0);
        Instantiate(pizza, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```